# Shortest path program

Tags: c++, shortest-path, adjacency-list

I want to write a shortest path program. I know how the algorithm works, but I don't know where to start

Initially, I thought of using an adjacency matrix but then decided against it because of space. Now I think adjacency list would be better.

Can anyone suggest me a websites or tutorials how to start writing adjacency list to give the input to the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might start with [Boost::Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/), which will provide you both mechanisms for storing graph data and a structure for writing an algorithm that consumes that data.